# Number Algorithm floats with dependency (subalgorithms environment)

Tags: numbering, floats, algorithms

What I have: 3 algorithms, like so:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption One}
...
\label{alg:one}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Two}
...
\label{alg:two}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Three}
...
\label{alg:three}
\end{algorithm}
```

What I want: I want algorithm 1 to be numbered in the same manner as the rest of the algorithms in the document, say, as **Algorithm 1**. Then I want Algorithms 2 and 3 to be numbered **Algorithm 1a** (or 1.1, or 1-a, or whatever) and **Algorithm 1b**.

Then I want numbering to continue as previous, so that the next algorithm is **Algorithm 2**. Can this be done, and if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could borrow the `subequations` definition from `amsmath`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\newcounter{parentalgorithm}
\newenvironment{subalgorithms}{%
  \refstepcounter{algorithm}%
  \protected@edef\theparentalgorithm{\thealgorithm}%
  \setcounter{parentalgorithm}{\value{algorithm}}%
  \setcounter{algorithm}{0}%
  \def\thealgorithm{\theparentalgorithm\alph{algorithm}}%
  \ignorespaces
}{%
  \setcounter{algorithm}{\value{parentalgorithm}}%
  \ignorespacesafterend
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{subalgorithms}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption One}
...
\label{alg:one}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Two}
...
\label{alg:two}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Three}
...
\label{alg:three}
\end{algorithm}

\end{subalgorithms}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's more elegant than my subalgorithms environment.  But the `\refstepcounter{algorithm}` line needs to be taken out otherwise the numbers go 1–2a–2b–3 instead of 1–1a–1b–2 as the OP wanted.

Comment: This works perfectly, with two caveats: as Matthew points out, the \refstecounter{algorithm} line has to be taken out, and the parent algorithm has to be outside the subalgorithms environment. Two simple fixes for an excellent solution!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the "easy" way to do it:

```
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption One}
...
\label{alg:one}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{1a}
\caption{Caption Two}
...
\label{alg:two}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{1b}
\caption{Caption Three}
...
\label{alg:three}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\setcounter{algorithm}{1}
\caption{Caption Four}
...
\label{alg:four}
\end{algorithm}
```

The "right" way to do it might be to create macros that turn on and off subnumbering.

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subalgorithm}
\newenvironment{subalgorithms}{
  \setcounter{subalgorithm}{0}
  % redefine the macro that sets the algorithm number to include the subalgorithm number
  \renewcommand{\thealgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}\alph{subalgorithm}}%
  % patch the macro that sets the caption head to unincrement to
  % - unincrement the algorithm counter
  % - increment the subalgorithm counter
  % - then do whatever it was supposed to do before
  \let\old@fnum@algorithm=\fnum@algorithm%
  \def\fnum@algorithm{%
    \addtocounter{algorithm}{-1}%
    \stepcounter{subalgorithm}%
    \old@fnum@algorithm}%
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption One}
...
\label{alg:one}
\end{algorithm} 

\begin{subalgorithms}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Two}
...
\label{alg:two}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Three}
...
\label{alg:three}
\end{algorithm}

\end{subalgorithms}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Four}
...
\label{alg:four}
\end{algorithm}
```

A third method would be to create a new float `subalgorithm` with a counter that reset with `algorithm`.

```
\makeatletter
\floatstyle{\ALG@floatstyle}
\newfloat{subalgorithm}{htbp}{loa}[algorithm]
\floatname{subalgorithm}{Subalgorithm}
\renewcommand{\thesubalgorithm}{\arabic{algorithm}\alph{subalgorithm}}
\@namedef{l@subalgorithm}{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\listofalgorithms

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption One}
...
\label{alg:one}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{subalgorithm}
\caption{Caption Two}
...
\label{alg:two}
\end{subalgorithm}

\lipsum[2-4]

\begin{subalgorithm}
\caption{Caption Three}
...
\label{subalg:three}
\end{subalgorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{Caption Four}
...
\label{alg:four}
\end{algorithm}
```

References:

- [float package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/) source/documentation
- [algorithm package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithm/) source/documentation